# How to create session persistance in Laravel?

Tags: php, session, laravel-5.5

I'm new in Laravel programming and my question is how to create a session persistance for all my application? Nowadays, when the user is logged, a sesssion is created and in every route in my application, a verification is executed to ensure that the current user has a session. So, if my app has 100 routes, in every one of them it will be verified if the session exists. Is there an easier way to do that?

Comment: Create stateful http-protocol then.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "make the session persistence"? If I understand your question correctly, just using middleware to protect your routes. For example,

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    .... // rest of your routes
});
```